# Batch file to find a replace a file path in a file

Tags: batch-file, replace, find

Long story short, I want to know how I can write a batch file to find a file path (inside of a .csproj file) that appears like this

`..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\file\inside\Repository.dll`

and replace it with the correct path name

```
'C:\Program Files\file\inside\Repository.dll'
```

Notice, how the files are the same. I have several files correctly defined in my .csproj files, it's just the path to get to them wrong. So I want to find and replace only the file path and not the file itself. So this is essentially find and replace part of a string and not the entire string.

Comment: You should show more valid examples of your `csproj` file

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "fpath=C:\Program Files\file\inside\csproj"   &REM set path to csproj files
SET "newext=.new"                                 &REM set extension for new files

SET "fname="
for /r "%fpath%" %%a in (*.csproj) DO SET "fname=%%~a"&CALL:process
goto:eof

:process
(FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('findstr /n "^" "%fname%"') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET "line=!line:*:=!"
    IF "!line:..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\file\inside\DataRepository.dll=!" neq "!line!" (
        SET "line=!line:..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\file\inside\DataRepository.dll=C:\Program Files\file\inside\DataRepository.dll!"
    )
    ECHO(!line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%fname%%newext%"
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement `f`, a la `FOR ... %v IN (...) DO ... %~fv` will resolve the path and make it a fully-qualified path.

So, the requirement to get this to work is to get the path to the file(s) in a FOR loop variable.

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%f IN (list_of_files.txt) DO @ECHO %%~ff
```

As for getting paths from a .CSPROJ file, I don't know the format. Can you say how the paths will be expressed? Are they XML element attributes or content? If they're not easy to find, this will be exceedingly unreliable depending on how the data is expressed.

Comment: This is how it looks across all files. The path structure is always identical in every .csproj file, but the .dll file is different. <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\ProgramFiles\file\inside\DataRepository.dll</HintPath>

Comment: How important is it to you that this be done in batch/CMD? Perl/Python/almost_anything would be much easier _and_ more reliable. Is the `<HintPath>` element guaranteed (by your reckoning) to be on a line by itself? Does it always have the same amount of whitespace at the beginning? I can craft a hackish batch script to do this, but it'll be cumbersome to read. If you start with something that can parse XML, you'd be way better off.